# How to post json data properly to Instagram OAuth2 protocol?

Tags: python, json, flask, oauth

I am working on a Flask website which uses Instagram's OAuth authentication service ([based on this description](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)). I am able to access Instagram and I get the code necessary for authentication, but at the final step I get an error stating that I do not have a "client_id" which I think I have provided.

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
import requests
import json

client_id = ""
client_secret = ""
redirect_uri = ""
authorization_url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.secret_key = 'development'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(authorization_url + "/?client_id=" + client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&scope=public_content&response_type=code")

@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    code = request.args.get('code')

    payload = {"client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
    "code": code}

    r = requests.post('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', data=json.dumps(payload))
    return r.text
```

Which returns an error:

```
{"error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "You must provide a client_id"}
```

I find this strange as I did provide a client_id in the payload.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It appears, that the payload does not have to be a json, but a simple dictionary.
with the following form it works:

```
r = requests.post('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', data=payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per RFC 7662 you need to send your request with Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoding (so rather than a JSON object you have a set of key=value separated by & having applied encodeURIComponent to each key and value). You also need the Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoding header in your request. You'll get back JSON.

So like below:
from urllib.parse import urlencode, quote_plus

// using your object from above
result = urlencode(payload, quote_via=quote_plus)

Then use the result text as the payload of your POST.